# fourier-otf and texlive 2022 with xelatex

Tags: xetex, fourier

The following code with xelatex :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

fails on Texlive 2022 on linux up to date (18/08/2022).

If i change the line 49 of `fourier-otf.sty` witch is : `\noexpand\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}` by `\noexpand\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math.otf}` it works !

Does anyone know a simpler solution ?

Comment: Ask the maintainer of the sty to adapt the code.

Comment: It would likely work as is if you made the texlive fonts available system-wide. For me I do `sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype /usr/share/fonts/texlive-ttf` and `sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype /usr/share/fonts/texlive-otf` to link those folders to the paths that are searched by fontconfig, then run `sudo fc-cache -fv`. Your sample works for me as is. You may need to adjust the paths depending on how you installed texlive and your distro's config. But not everyone might want those fonts systemwide, so follow Ulrike's advice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point! Thanks for pointing out this glitch in `fourier-otf.sty`.
`xelatex` looks for system fonts and can find TeXLive fonts only by filename (not by font name).

So your patch is correct. apply it to your copy of `fourier-otf.sty`.
I'll do the same for the next release.

The other work around is, as already mentioned, to declare TeXLive fonts as system fonts. Adding all `.otf` and `.ttf` fonts found in the TexLive to system fonts on Linux using can be done with `fontconfig`.
Here is what I do (Linux Debian):

- create a link `current` in (say) /usr/local/texlive pointing to 2022 (this year) and update it every year. So you don't have to change the paths every year!
- create a file `09-texlive.conf` in `/etc/conf.d` referencing the directories

  `/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype`

  `/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype`

  `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/opentype`

  `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype`
  though
  (copy the proper syntax from the other files found in `/etc/conf.d` and have a look at the `fontconfig` man page.)
- run the command `fc-cache -fsv` once, and then every time you add fonts to these directories, at least when you switch to a new TeXLive release.

The main advantage of the latter approach is that all these TeXlive fonts can also be used by other programs (`libreoffice` f.i.). This hides your problem on my system though :-(